# How do I get callgrind to dump source line information?

Tags: c, profiling, valgrind, code-analysis, callgrind

I'm trying to profile a shared library on GNU/Linux which does real-time audio processing, so performance is important.  I run another program which hooks it up to the audio input and output of my system, and profile that with callgrind.

Looking at the results in KCacheGrind, I get great information about what functions are taking up most of my time.  However, it won't let me look at the line by line information, and instead says I need to compile it with debugging symbols and run the profiling again.

The program which I am profiling is not compiled with debug symbols, but the library is.  And I know this, because interestingly, source code annotations for *cachegrind* work fine.

When I run callgrind, it says the default is to dump source line information, but it just isn't doing that.  Is there some way I could force it to, or figure out what's stopping it?

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but can you recompile your app with debug symbols?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `--dump-instr=yes --trace-jump=yes` to get the instruction level information?

Comment: I was not using those options, but running it again with those options, I still cannot get it to show source lines.

Comment: Those options show the assembly instruction level, not the C/C++ source level.

Answer (score 0):

As you have correctly identified `callgrind` by default is performing the event count at source code level.
Quoting from the man page of `callgrind` -

```
--dump-line=<no|yes> [default: yes]
```

But then during post-processing, you have to provide the path to source files for the `callgrind_annotate` tool using the `--include` option for it to generate the annotated source-code with line by line information.
Quoting from the man page of `callgrind_annotate` -

```
       -I, --include=<dir>
           Add dir to the list of directories to search for source files.
```

This is the sample command that worked for me -

```
callgrind_annotate --auto=yes --include=/home/sangeek/source callgrind.out.15078 > callgrind.annotate.txt
```

Also please note that the source-code level annotated report is placed after the usual `file:function` summary report in the file. So, you'll have to scroll past those in the report to reach them.